# Adding onselectionchange to vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i'm trying to implement a text selection listener to display a toolbar for some custom options

```
<script>

export default {
  name: "home",
  created() {
    document.onselectionchange = function() {
      this.showMenu();
    };
  },
  data() {
    return {
      ...
    };
  },
  methods: {
    showMenu() {
      console.log("show menu");
      }
    }

</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

but it still display that can't call showMenu of undefined, so i tried in this way:

```
  created() {
    vm = this;
    document.onselectionchange = function() {
      vm.showMenu();
    };
  },
```

so, nothing changed =(

i need to use this selectionchange because its the only listener that i can add that will handle desktop and mobile together, other method i should implement a touchup, touchdown and its not working for devices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functions declared the classic way do have their own `this`. You can fix that by either explicitly binding `this` using `Function.prototype.bind()` or by using an ES6 arrow function (which does not have an own `this`, preserving the outer one).

**The second problem** is that if you have more than one of those components you've shown, each will re-assign (and thus, *overwrite*) the listener if you attach it using the assignment `document.onselectionchange =`. This would result in only the last select element working as you expect because it's the last one assigned.

To fix that, I suggest you use `addEventListener()` instead:

```
document.addEventListener('selectionchange', function() {
  this.showMenu();
}.bind(this));
```

or

```
document.addEventListener('selectionchange', () => {
  this.showMenu();
});
```

A third solution stores a reference to `this` and uses that in a closure:

```
const self = this;
document.addEventListener('selectionchange', function() {
  self.showMenu();
});
```